# Filter a 2d array by a static value and a column in another 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, intersect

I have 2 arrays where they have some common `id` values, but the keys for these `id` keys differ slightly.

```
$comps = [
  [
    'c_id' => '123',
    'status' => 'active'
  ],
  [
    'c_id' => '456',
    'status' => 'destroyed'
  ],
  [
    'c_id' => '789',
    'status' => 'active'
  ]
];

$rests = [
  [
    'r_id' => 123,
    'extra' => 'some extra info for r_id 123'
  ],
  [
    'r_id' => 456,
    'extra' => 'some extra info for r_id 456'
  ]
];
```

My objective here is to return all entries of the `$rests` array that have corresponding entries within the `$comps` array that have both matching ID values and a `status => active`.

How can one achieve this?

I have seen and used `array_uintersect()` in the past, however I can't seem to get this to work in the desired way.

Comment: Did your attempt resemble [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73552928/2943403)?

Comment: @mickmackusa Something like that, but I'm working on PHP <7, so I had to do it longhand.

Comment: Related: [How to filter multidimensional array based on another multidimensional array of exclusions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60223494/2943403) and [Filter 2D array using another 2D array where differently keyed column values intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39528364/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this with a nested foreach loop.

```
$matches = [];
foreach ($rests as $rest) {
    foreach ($comps as $comp) {
        if ($rest['r_id'] === $comp['c_id'] && $comp['status'] === 'active') {
            $matches[] = $rest;
        }
    }
}

print_r($matches);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [r_id] => 123
            [extra] => some extra info for r_id 123
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `array_uintersect()` implementation with the two rules.

This is a good choice because PHP optimizes the comparisons by using a sorting algorithm under the hood.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ngfra))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $comps,
        $rests,
        fn($a, $b) =>
            [$a['c_id'] ?? $a['r_id'], ($a['status'] ?? 'active') === 'active']
            <=>
            [$b['c_id'] ?? $b['r_id'], ($b['status'] ?? 'active') === 'active']
    )
);
```

With outdated PHP: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aA2bJ))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $comps,
        $rests,
        function($a, $b) {
            return [$a['c_id'] ?? $a['r_id'], ($a['status'] ?? 'active') === 'active']
                   <=>
                   [$b['c_id'] ?? $b['r_id'], ($b['status'] ?? 'active') === 'active'];
        }
    )
);
```

---

I don't think that it's shameful to pre-filter the `$comps` array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3H9rr))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        array_filter($comps, function($row) { return $row['status'] === 'active'; }),
        $rests,
        function($a, $b) {
            return ($a['c_id'] ?? $a['r_id'])
                   <=>
                   ($b['c_id'] ?? $b['r_id']);
        }
    )
);
```

---

If interested in a brute force nested loop approach, then avoid doing useless cycles by conditionally breaking and continuing. I mean, think about it, why bother looping on the rests array if the given comps array can be disqualified early. Furthermore, after you make an id match and push the data into the result array, stop the inner loop. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gGqTr))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($comps as $comp) {
    if ($comp['status'] !== 'active') {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($rests as $rest) {
        if ($rest['r_id'] == $comp['c_id']) {
            $result[] = $rest;
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```